# Solr fails to index text field

Tags: solr, lucene, full-text-search

When trying to index documents with `text_general` fields I get the following error:

```
Exception writing document id 93cf6aeb-54b0-471a-9325-5b8e95801131 to the index; possible analysis error: cannot change field "content" from index options=DOCS to inconsistent index options=DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS
```

The document I attempted to index looks as follows:

```
{
    "filename": "FooBar.pdf",
    "content": "my test"
}
```

The schema definition for this field is:

```
  <field name="content" type="text_general" uninvertible="true" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>
```

With the field type defined as:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

How do I succcessfully index a document with a `text_general` field?

Comment: This is caused by there already being content indexed for the field that was indexed with a different field type. Delete the index and re-index your content.

Comment: @MatsLindh your suggestion solved my problem, if you post an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is caused by there already being content indexed for the field that was indexed with a different field type. Delete the index and re-index your content.

Comment: I have delete content for particular 1 project, should I need to delete all the project's content in that doc collection? Because after deleting and re-indexing content also give the same error. Can you also say, from solr admin panel UI, how can I delete the index of the field that was have previous field type

Comment: Anything in the collection that has changed its field type has to be removed. I'm not sure what you mean by project, but a collection or a core has to be completely empty before reindexing. If you're using collections, you might have to recreate the collection itself, while for old-style cores you can remove the index directory for the core from the underlying disk

Comment: Solved the issue by adding required property omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" in schema. Thanks for quick reply.

Comment: In case of a simple core (no collection used) emptying the entire index and re-indexing solved the problem in my case.

Comment: You might need to reload the core after deleting all indexes, especially if you changed some field types.

Answer (score 2):

We're using Sitcore Managed Cloud with SearchStax for Solr and I got this error. I logged into the Solr Admin and went to "Collections" in the left nav menu. From there I chose the collection that gave the error on Rebuild and clicked "Reload". After reloading the collection, I was able to rebuild successfully. Not sure if this will help anyone else.

[image: Screenshot]